# C++ Missing Argument List - Class Method

Tags: c++, class, methods, arguments, glut

I want to use a class method as the GLUT disply function. The way I did it:

```
glutDisplayFunc(this->gameTick);
```

But I get an error: missing argument list. Some of my code:

```
class Game
{
public:
    void gameTick();
}

void Game::gameTick()
{
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: You're missing the `()` after your function call `gameTick`.  It should look like `glutDisplayFunc(gameTick())`.  However, without seeing where (the context of) your call to `glutDisplayFunc()` it's impossible to know if this will work for directly you or not.

Comment: glutDisplayFunc() is from the GLUT framework, it's not my function

Comment: I'm aware of that.  But where you call it is important for the question at hand.  If you call it from within another member function of the `Game` class, then simply calling `glutDisplayFunc(gameTick());` is the correct answer to your question.  If not, then it is more complicated than that.

Comment: I use the function in the constructor of the class. I tried doing it like this: glutDisplayFunc(gameTick()); but then I get this error: void is incompatible width void (*)()

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a class method this way. Try making it static or use a non-class function.

The static method syntax would then be written

```
glutDisplayFunc(Game::gameTick);
```

`this->gameTick` tries to call `gameTick()` and this is why it's missing the argument list in parenthesis.